# Debugging in GX - fails to work in Windows 8.1

Tags: genexus

Cannot get GX debugger to work. I get the "Warning: Login debuggable program. No debugger found at: sputnik" error (like the Wiki says).

GX exe is allowed through the firewall. Started GX as administrator. Turned off the firewall. No success :(

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to connect using telnet, from the machine where the application runs to the GeneXus, like the wiki says ? ( ref.: http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?11013 )

Comment: Using Telnet, I get the following response: **Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 6776: Connect failed** -- This tells me what I already knew; it doesn't work. But why? What is the solution

Comment: If you are using x evolution 2 upgrade 5 or higher try opening %Document and Settings%\<User>\Application Data\Artech\Genexus\<version>\Environment.config and edit the section <General> setting
<add key="DGXPORT" value="6776" /> . Make sure that the firewall doesn't block you

Comment: Hi, the section was already there but the value said "30104". I changed it to "6776", rebooted, rebuild all etc., but still, GX will not stop at the break point.

Comment: Try using netstat command in order to know which ports are occupied. (http://qbit.com.mx/blog/2012/05/08/como-saber-que-puertos-estan-ocupados-y-que-programa-los-utiliza-en-windows/). 
I think that wheter your port is occupied, not available because of firewall settings, or localhost does not exist (you may have some setting in windows hosts file that redirects, or something like that).

Comment: Using tasklist, I got the PID that GX is running on and using netstat, the port assigned to the process on the PID (in my case #964) is 6776 with a state of "LISTENING". So, there doesn't seem to be an issue here. I also created additional new GX rules specifically targeting port 6776 but no joy. I re-ran the telnet check and again, it said it could not open connection to the host. This is really frustrating. It worked in Windows 7 but doesn't in Windows 8.1.

Comment: Are you prototyping with Ruby? In that case, we 've found an issue in Ruby Generator's standard classes